# Conversion of RDA to CSV goes wrong

Tags: r, csv, rda

Since this morning, I am trying to convert the Smoothies table within the [SensorMineR Dataset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SensoMineR/index.html) using R Studio, but when I do it, the CSV created file is not well tabulated. You can verify it yourself by running the following commands :

```
smoothiesData <- load('smoothies.rda')
write.csv(get(smoothiesData), file = "smoothies.csv")
```

You can see that the columns are not well separated, I tried running the following command, but it doesn't change anything

```
write.csv(get(smoothiesData), file = "smoothies.csv", sep=",")
```

Can you tell me how should I proceed ?

Comment: When loading the data, the data gets stored in a data.frame called `smoothies`, so please just `write.csv(smoothies, file="smoothies.csv")` should do the trick. To be sure you can add `quotes = TRUE` to the write.csv call.

Answer (score 0):

You have called `get` which returns the value of a named object.

To make it work you can go the simple way:

```
write.csv(smoothiesData, file = "smoothies.csv", sep=",")
```

or you can use the name:

```
write.csv(get("smoothiesData"), file = "smoothies.csv", sep=",")
```

See `?get`

Comment: Did you check with the original .rda file? It's not working since the data.frame is not called `smoothiesData`.

Comment: @hannes101 I provided a general solution. About the naming of the variable I can't tell. Is it producing an error on your `load` call?